# Laravel. Как отключить системную миграцию при развертывании проекта

Tags: laravel, миграция

При развертывании проекта laravel 10 имеются стандартные миграции по созданию таблиц - migrations, users, failed_job и прочие. Если некоторые миграции мне не нужны, возможно ли каким-то образом их отключить без ковыряния в исходниках самой laravel?

Comment: Вы же можете их просто удалить. Но вообще имейте ввиду, что это может иметь свои последствия, например с failed jobs, так как там Laravel хранит информацию о задачах очереди, которые не удалось выполнить после заданного числа попыток.

Comment: @Simon, имеете в виду удалить системные миграции(но где они находятся)? Или удалить таблицы?

Comment: Те три миграции о которых Вы говорите, находятся в директории database/migrations, либо я Вас не верно понял

Comment: @Simon, а если миграция в вендорах лежит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрел вопрос и комментарии.

1. Правильно пишут, что те миграции о которых вы говорите находяться в `database/migrations`. А все остольное не сам исходный `Laravel`.
2. В исходном `Laravel` нету миграций в `vendor`-ах. Если у вас есть такие пакеты в которых есть миграция. То вы уже должны посмотреть сам пакет, его документацию что бы понять какие конфиги там нужны для той или иной миграции, или как от них избавиться.

Вопрос не однозначен. Я дал примерно вам понять как все это сделано. И куда дальше смотреть.

Comment: Да, все верно. Просто думал мб каким-то образом можно будет в конфиге прописать условие. Если миграция или таблица такая, то не выполняем)

Comment: @KordDEM Нет стандартные просто удали. А то что в пакетах, уже посмотри их доки.